# Cycling through divs in bootstrap indefinitely?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I need to loop through 4 divs arranged in a 2x2 way (cycle=highlighting the selected div) indefinitely. I can't think of the j-query required to do this.

```
<div class="contentwrap-black" id="current-features">
<div id="content" class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <!-- ----------- IPHONE  --------- -->

                <div class="span4" id="iphone-white">
                    <img class="iphone-white-img" src="img/iphone-wht-front.png" alt="">
                </div>

                <!-- ----------- BANNER --------- -->

                <div class="span8">
                    <h1 class="current-features-banner">CURRENT FEATURES</h1>

                    <div class="row-fluid">

                        <!-- ----------- LEFT COLUMN --------- -->

                        <div class="span6" id="">
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <div class="span12 content" id="">
                                    <h3>Heading-1</h3>
                                    <p> Paragraph-1</p>
                                </div>


                                    <div class="span12" id="divider">
                                        <hr>
                                    </div>



                                    <div class="span12 content" id="">
                                        <h3>Heading-2</h3>
                                        <p> Content-2</p>
                                        <hr id="line"> <!-- THIS LINE IS HIDDEN UNTIL MOBILE SIZE-->
                                    </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- ----------- RIGHT COLUMN --------- -->

                        <div class="span6" id="">
                            <div class="row-fluid set">
                                <div class="span12 content" id="">
                                    <h3>heading-3</h3>
                                    <p>paragraph-3
                                </div>


                                    <div class="span12 trap" id="divider">
                                        <hr>
                                    </div>



                                    <div class="span12 content " id="">
                                        <h3>heading-4</h3>
                                        <p>paragraph-4.</p>
                                    </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- ----------- END OF COLUMNS --------- -->

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The 4 divs I want to loop between are the ones containing the class "content", highlighting each div for 2 seconds and then switching to the next one.

Comment: Dont know what your cycling with, but jQuery.detach().append() should do the trick. Remove from top, add to bottom !

Comment: @Robert could you explain how that would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not cover your animation or whatever you want to do, but it shows how to keep it cycling indefinitely

```
function cycle() {
    $(".container .content")
        .last()
        .detach()
        .prependTo(".container");
}

// and in the inverse sense
function cycle() {
    $(".container .content")
        .first()
        .detach()
        .appendTo(".container");
}
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/XuHQv/

---

Ok so color cycling it is http://jsfiddle.net/XuHQv/1/

```
    setInterval(function() {
        var items  = $(".container .content");
        var length = items.length;     

        items.each(function(i, ele) {
            if ($(ele).hasClass("color")) {
                $(ele).removeClass("color");

                if (i < (length-1)) {
                  $(items[i+1]).addClass("color");
                }
                else {
                    $(items[0]).addClass("color");
                }    

                return false;
            }                
        });
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: thanks, but i want to loop through the div automatically (without me clicking) . That means every 2 seconds a different div will get a lets say green background. So after every two seconds that green background will go to the next div.

Comment: jQuery.animate in that case. I thought you wanted the divs to move around

Comment: oh sorry for confusing you, i just need the background to change. How would .animate work?

Comment: No need for animate actually ..just got stuck on some code for a bit :)

Comment: yes! that's it, thanks a lot mate! adding two classes in items variable was the trick all along.

Answer (score 1):

I got a fiddle for you:  http://jsfiddle.net/tkjzZ/4/

EDIT: I fixed needing the flag classes. You still need to start with one highlighted though.

```
    function changeHighlight()
{
    if($(".content.highlight").is(":last"))
    {
        $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
        $(".content").first().addClass("highlight");
    }
    else
    {
        $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight").next().addClass("highlight");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(changeHighlight, 2000); //2 sec
});
```

Comment: the only porblem is that i can't seem to highlight the div on the right column. It starts on the left and then stops. I need it to continue onto the right column as well.

Comment: Little upvote from me. I find your solution more elegant, since you are not resorting to a loop like me.